# How to include another website in another using PHP

Tags: php

the title says it all. I've tried using iFrames, but it's not what I need. I have a website where it's echoing data (users on the site, etc..) - but I want to be able to display this data being posted on another website, using PHP to grab the text from the website.

I don't want to use iFrames, since I don't want it in PHP & I don't want the actual link where it's coming from to be shown; so I want it to be all done backend.

Website 1 contains the information I want to be displayed on website 2. For website 2 to access the data; they need to load http://example.com/page.php - where it echo's all the information. And I just want website 2 to echo/display the data in text format. If that makes sense.

Comment: use `file_get_contents` or `cURL` to download the second website into a variable in the PHP script.

Comment: @Barmar And make sure that the other site ALLOWS you to do that - not just that you can. Otherwise it is infringement on the highest order.

Comment: hm, maybe using Curl http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php but is weird the idea why do u want do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.address.com/something'); // Can be locally too, for example: something.php
echo $file;
```

Be carefull, this method is not 100% safe, **until You are not 100% sure** that the url you are echoing is safe.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To "include" a page, you can use `file_get_contents`, which returns the file contents as a string. All you have to do is echo the returned string and you're good.

A few things though:

- Relative URLs in the page you're scraping won't work too well. You'll have to convert them to a fixed URL
- It's rude to scrape someone's website. If you don't own it, ask for permission.
- You said at the end of your question that you want it in text format. If you mean you want it in plain text, not formatted HTML, you'll want to call `htmlspecialchars` on it.
- You aren't always going to be certain that the page you're scraping is kosher. It could be hacked or otherwise violated, which would put your users at risk too.